# Enable/disable the button from other form

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to disable the button from other form  from current form and enable the button again after clicking reset button.

Comment: Man pls divide you the question and google it before posting

Comment: Already find solution but I can't find that's why I need help from here.

Answer (score 0):

Add a public method where you control the button state as disabled or enabled in this form,then transfer this form as parameter to other form

Comment: Can u please show me with some kind of code sample.